# Epithet: a qualifying title

Tags: vocabulary

If someone's first name is followed by another word that describes one of his qualities, can we call it 'Epithet'? This is usual in the Arabic language. An example is:

> Rashid Ghani

The word Ghani means: "rich"

**So, is the word "Ghani" an epithet?**

Someone said to me: it is a suffix. I didn't agree because it is not a suffix. A suffix occurs at the end of a word e.g. (wonder-ful, depend-ent, act-ion); and, it is a part of that word.

Comment: Is "Ghani" part of the first name? Some names (especially in the southern US) are "double barreled" such as "Emma Grace" but the second part is just a name, not an epithet, which is more obvious in something like "Mary Kate".

Comment: no, it's not part of the name in documents but is  only added while calling

Comment: So "Rashid Ghani" means something like "Rashid the rich"?

Comment: Where would it be used? Only among close friends, by acquaintances and strangers, or more formally eg in business or professional contexts, or by family? Is it a respectful thing, or more to poke fun?

Comment: Yes, it is (*an epithet*). Refer to [What Does the Word "Epithet" Mean?](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-epithet-1690668) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet)

Answer (score 3):

Before reading your question, I didn't know that "epithet" could mean anything other than "disparaging or abusive word or phrase".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epithet) has this to say:

> Nowadays, *epithet* is usually used negatively, with the meaning "a disparaging word or phrase," but it wasn't always that way. *Epithet* comes from Greek *epitithenai*, meaning "to put on" or "to add." In its oldest sense, *epithet* is simply a descriptive word or phrase, especially one joined by fixed association to the name of someone or something, as in "Ivan the Great" or the Homeric phrase "wine-dark sea."

So it seems that "Ghani" *is* an epithet, but I think few English speakers today would understand the meaning, and most would think you'd used the wrong word.

English doesn't tend to use words in that way, so we don't have a common term for it that everyone understands. Some near terms include **title**, **title of respect**, **honorary title**, or **honorific**. None of them, however, make exactly clear what you're talking about since we barely have this concept in English.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of the name '*Rashid Ghani*', where you say that 'Ghani' means '*rich*', just sounds like a personal name to me, either given or assumed.

The word 'epithet' is really defined as "*an adjective added to a person's name or a phrase used instead of it*". Examples from history would include "William the Conqueror", or "Ivan the Terrible", who gained these epithets by reputation. Modern examples might include sportspersons such as William "The Refridgerator" Perry, who I believe was so-called because of his physical stature.

In direct answer to your question, unless this word meaning 'rich' directly describes the person, then I'd have to say *no* - it is not an 'epithet', even if it derives from some adjective or title. Epithets are normally earned through actions and reputation.

In western cultures, there are many surnames that derive from historic professions, statuses and the like. For example, occupations like *Baker* and *Cooper* (someone who makes barrels) are common surnames today, likely handed down through generations from an ancestor who actually did those jobs. If someone *named* 'Baker' today was by trade a baker, this would likely be a coincidence, unless the trade had stayed in the family for centuries. So, these are not 'epithets', even though they may have derived from one. Similarly, *given names* (forenames) that have meanings are not really epithets, because the person may not live up to them!

I am aware that, in some cultures, people take on new names at various stages in their life which may reflect a change in status. Even so, unless they directly describe the person in a unique, identifying way, rather than just a generic title that means they are a husband or a wife, for example, then I would still argue it is not a true epithet.

Comment: According to OP's comment, "it's not part of the name in documents", so it's not a family name or a given name or anything official like that.

Comment: @laurel that might be a cultural thing, though - and I've tried to cover that. I used to work in government offices where we insisted that all persons gave us a forename and a surname. Some foreign nationals wrote things like 'wife' as surname, because they didn't have one. I don't understand the cultural reason why someone would take the name 'Rich' but I get the impression it isn't because they are wealthy. That would be some brag, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Astralbee OP said it's "only added in calling," which I assume means 'rich' is something *other people* call Rashid, *not* something he calls himself.  In this case it seems like it actually *would* be an "epithet," just like "the Conqueror" or "the Terrible."  If I understand the question correctly, it seems like this person is known as "Rashid the Rich"